# Method to dynamically add fragment to another fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm building an app that has `MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` which uses a `CalendarFragment extends Fragment` that is populated by any number of `ShiftRowFragment extends Fragment`.

I want to build a method to dynamically add a `ShiftRowFragment` to the `CalendarFragment`.  the `ShiftRowFragment` contains dynamic values such as the Date and Time as `String`.

Here is my `CalendarFragment.java`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        addDay();
        addDay();

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_fragment, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    private void addDay() {

        ShiftRowFragment shiftFragment = new ShiftRowFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.llShifts, shiftFragment).commit();

    }
}
```

Here is what the `ShiftRowFragment.java` looks like:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ShiftRowFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ShiftRowFragment newInstance(int index) {
        ShiftRowFragment f = new ShiftRowFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shiftrow_fragment, container,
                false);

        // load calendar

        return view;
    }
}
```

Frankly, I'm confused about the documentation I've read.  Something is supposed to happen in the `newInstance` method of `ShiftRowFragment`, but I'm unsure of what exactly.  The current code displays two ShiftRow's with the default values (specified in the shiftrow_fragment.xml file).

Lastly, the `shiftrow_fragment.xml` file contains the following `TextViews` that need to be dynamically populated.

- `tvDateIconMonth` - Holds a String value such as "Jan.", "Feb.", etc.
- `tvDateIconDay` - Holds a String value such as "Mon.", "Tue.", etc.
- `tvExpiration` - Holds a String value such as "Today", "Tomorrow", "In 3 Days", etc.
- Also, I need to set the Tag on the parent `LinearLayout` that contains the above `TextViews` to an Index of some kind so I can access the `Fragment`'s children.

How can I fix my `addDay()` method to do what I need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `addDay()` method should look like this:

```
private void addDay(String date, String time) {

    ShiftRowFragment shiftFragment = ShiftRowFragment.newInstance(date, time);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.llShifts, shiftFragment).commit();

}
```

And your `ShiftRowFragment.java` should look like this:

```
public class ShiftRowFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String BUNDLE_DATE = "DATE"'
private static final String BUNDLE_TIME = "TIME"'

    public static ShiftRowFragment newInstance(String date, String time) {
        ShiftRowFragment f = new ShiftRowFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(BUNDLE_DATE, date);
        args.putString(BUNDLE_TIME, time);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shiftrow_fragment, container,
            false);

        // reference textviews etc.

        String date;
        String time;
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            date = savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_DATE);
            time = savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_TIME);
        }

        tvDateIconMonth.setText(date);
        // etc.

        return view;
     }
}
```

Note: I think you should pass date and time as Date not String, because you want to do some date and time calculations in fragment. Maybe I am wrong but I think so, because you mentioned TextView `tvExpiration`. In case I am right, you will change `String` to `Date` and you will pass Date to bundle this way:

```
i.putLong(BUNDLE_DATE, date.getTime());
```

and you will get date in fragment this way:

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(i.getLong(BUNDLE_DATE, -1));
```

Comment: Never pass dates. They are not thread safe. You can easily pass the long timestamp and create a date object in the fragment.  If you want to pass dates use Joda DateTime objects they are so much better than Date objects.